# Different location for each language

Tags: nginx

Our server is set up like this:

```
/var
    /www
        /website
            /language1
                /public
            /language2
                /public
            /language3
                /public
            /language4
                /public
```

So I try to set up the right nginx config and need to pass on the locations to different folders. I tried this:

```
location /language1 {
    alias /var/www/website/language1/public;

    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?sef_rewrite=1&$args;

    location = /language1/favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /language1/robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css|ttf|svg|eot|woff)$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/(.*?)\/(.*)$ /$2 last;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 10m;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size    512k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size          512k;
        fastcgi_buffers           16 512k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout         1200;
    }
}
```

Only now I keep getting 404 or file not found errors, whatever I try. I changed alias to root, did PHP location outside the /language1 location, etc. Anyone who can point me into the right direction?

Comment: We'll need log messages at the *very* least.

Comment: Did you really create completely different applications for each language? This is not the best way to go about it. See your framework's localization help.

Comment: I know @MichaelHampton, problem is we do have different business models in different countries going under the same name.. So, in one country we for example are a webshop, in another country we only sell to dealers and have a dealer portal. They are all very different from eachother and even use different frameworks.

Comment: Hmm. They probably should have different domain names, too.